# How can I grab values from a database, sum them, and display them in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, mysqli

I would like to sum a column of a database with certain WHERE criteria then display it on the webpage, but am unsure of how to do so.

Here is what I have so far for my function in my controller.

```
public function get_hours() {
    $user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');
    $this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);
    $this->db->select_sum('USER_WORK_HOURS');
    $data = $this->db->get('user_hours');
    $hours = $data->row()->USER_WORK_HOURS;
    echo $hours;
}
```

This will take me to a blank page and not display anything.

I have also tried to echo out $data, but get an error saying it could not convert it to string.

Here is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="container">
   <h1>Members</h1>
   <?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
   echo "</pre>";
   $this->load->helper('date');
   echo "<h2>";
   echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   echo "</h2>";
   ?>
   <a href="<?php echo 'clock_in' ?>">Clock In</a> <br />
   <br />
   <a href="<?php echo 'clock_out' ?>">Clock Out</a> <br />
   <br />
   <a href="<?php echo 'get_hours' ?>">Get Hours</a> <br />
   <br />
   <a href="<?php echo 'main/logout' ?>">Logout</a> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other info:

- The column I am trying to sum is in the TIME format in phpmyadmin

If any other info is needed let me know.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

An answer has been found. Thank you Putu Yoga and Bishnu Paudel for your help.

Corrected code:

```
public function get_hours()
{

$user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');

$this->db->select('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORK_HOURS` ) ) ) AS totalHours'); 
$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);
$hours= $this->db->get('user_hours')->row()->totalHours;

echo $hours;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function get_hours()
{

$user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');

$this->db->select('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORK_HOURS` ) ) ) AS totalHours'); 
$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);
$hours= $this->db->get('user_hours')->row()->totalHours;

echo $hours;

}
```

Comment: beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, you **can not** directly call `SUM()` on `TIME` datatype in mysql. You must convert it first to numeric by using `TIME_TO_SEC()` function, and then convert it back to `TIME`.

I will give you the direct SQL example, about this approach:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORKS_HOUR` ) ) ) AS timeSum
   FROM YourTableName WHERE `USER_EMAIL` = $email
```

Maybe you can test the SQL query first on phpmyadmin before run in the real application. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the response. I ran it in phpmyadmin and it runs but shows as NULL. Not sure why

Comment: well, it indicate your sql isn't correct. Try run without `WHERE` clause, is it work?

Comment: It ran with and without the WHERE clause. Just displays NULL either  way

Comment: strange, it is works fine with me. I think some of your `USER_WORKS_HOUR` value is `NULL`, try add `WHERE USER_WORKS_HOUR IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I got it to work, the wrong column name was there. it is USER_WORK_HOURS. Instead of USER_WORKS_HOUR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure but may be work.

```
public function get_hours()
{

$user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');

$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);

$this->db->select_sum('USER_WORK_HOURS');

$data = $this->db->get('user_hours');

$hours = $data->row();

echo $hours->USER_WORK_HOURS;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function get_hours()
{


    $user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');

    $this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);

    $this->db->select_sum('USER_WORK_HOURS');

    $data = $this->db->get('user_hours');

    $hours = $data->result();

    echo $hours;

}
```

Comment: This gives me a notice: "Array to string conversion" and displays 'Array' on the page

Comment: try var_dump($hours);

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["USER_WORK_HOURS"]=> NULL } }

Comment: USER_WORK_HOURS is your  field

Comment: That is the column I am trying to sum and display, yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99760/discussion-between-naseeba-c-and-ddrossi93).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function get_hours()
{

$user_email = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');

$this->db->select('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORK_HOURS` ) ) ) AS workduration '); 
$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $user_email);
$query = $this->db->get('user_hours');
$hours = $query->result();

echo $hours[0]->workduration;
}
```